# Comparing children of ancestor element in lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

XML :

```
<leg:heading nline="true">  
  <desig inline="true" searchtype="SECT-NUM"> 
    <designum>
      <refpt type="ext" id="USM.A000001y1966e.S1"/>1.
    </designum> 
  </desig>  
  <title inline="true" searchtype="SECT-TITLE"> 
    <refpt type="ext" id="USM.A000001y1966e.S1"/>Short title, commencement and application
  </title> 
</leg:heading>
```

I want to remove the refpt child of title if both title and designum contains refpt.

My Code :

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//leg:heading',namespaces={'leg':'http://www.lexis-nexis.com/glp/leg'}):
    for element in elem.getiterator():
        if(element.tag=='refpt'):
            print(element.tag.getparent())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I want to remove the `refpt` child of `title` if both `title` and `designum` contains `refpt`"*

The following XPath should return `refpt` elements to be removed according to the criteria mentioned above :

```
//leg:heading[desig/designum/refpt]/title/refpt
```

If you need to make sure that you only remove `refpt` under `title` when it has matching `id` with the one under `designum`, try this XPath :

```
//leg:heading/title/refpt[@id = ../../desig/designum/refpt/@id]
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton.Very  thanks it helped me to get the desired result.

Comment: If I remove the element  using elem=elem.getparent().remove(elem),than it also removes the text of title element.. can you please help in this?

Comment: @NavinDalal That's because the text is considered *tail* of the `refpt` element in `lxml` tree model. I think you'll need to manually reference/copy `refpt.tail` to a variable and add it to the parent element after removing the `refpt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It helped me a lot to understand.